# strsplit into data.frame with incomplete input

Tags: string, r, dataframe

I try to split a vector of strings into a data.frame object and for a fixed order this isn't a problem (e.g. like written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069076/split-column-at-delimiter-in-data-frame)), but in my particular case the columns for the future data-frame are not complete in the string objects. This is how the output should look like for an toy input:

```
input <- c("an=1;bn=3;cn=45",
           "bn=3.5;cn=76",
           "an=2;dn=5")

res <- do.something(input)

> res
      an  bn  cn  dn
[1,]  1   3   45  NA
[2,]  NA  3.5 76  NA
[3,]  2   NA  NA  5
```

I am looking now for a function `do.something`that can do that in a efficient way. My naive solution at the moment would be to loop over the input objects, `strsplit` those for `;` then `strsplit` them again for `=` and then fill the `data.frame` result by result. 
Is there any way to do that more R-alike? I am afraid doing that element by element would take quite a long time for a long vector `input`.

EDIT: Just for completeness, my naive solution looks like this:

```
  do.something <- function(x){
    temp <- strsplit(x,";")
    temp2 <- sapply(temp,strsplit,"=")
    ul.temp2 <- unlist(temp2)
    label <- sort(unique(ul.temp2[seq(1,length(ul.temp2),2)]))
    res <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(label)))
    colnames(res) <- label
    for(i in 1:length(temp)){
      for(j in 1:length(label)){
        curInfo <- unlist(temp2[[i]])
        if(sum(is.element(curInfo,label[j]))>0){
          res[i,j] <- curInfo[which(curInfo==label[j])+1]
        }
      }
    }
    res
  }
```

EDIT2:
Unfortunately my large input data looks like this (entries without '=' possible):

```
input <- c("an=1;bn=3;cn=45",
           "an;bn=3.5;cn=76",
           "an=2;dn=5")
```

so I cannot compare the given answers to my problem at hand. My naive solution for that is

```
do.something <- function(x){
    temp <- strsplit(x,";")
    tempNames <- sort(unique(sapply(strsplit(unlist(temp),"="),"[",1)))
    res <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(tempNames)))
    colnames(res) <- tempNames

    for(i in 1:length(temp)){
      curSplit <- strsplit(unlist(temp[[i]]),"=")
      curNames <- sapply(curSplit,"[",1)
      curValues <- sapply(curSplit,"[",2)
      for(j in 1:length(tempNames)){
        if(is.element(colnames(res)[j],curNames)){
          res[i,j] <- curValues[curNames==colnames(res)[j]]
        }
      }
    }
    res
  }
```

Comment: are your column names always two characters long?

Comment: Okay, sorry that was misleading. No, they aren't. They can be everything between 2 and 10 Characters.

Comment: I edited my solution. It now uses just base package and should handle missing numbers efficiently.

Comment: The solutions using `rbind.fill` are all good, but they'll be *terribly slow*. [Check this post for fast solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308551/do-callrbind-list-for-uneven-number-of-column/17309310#17309310). I think that's what you're looking for. I've not checked Simon's answer yet, but I'm guessing that'll be better than the `rbind.fill` based solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out. As you wrote, the plyr are still pretty slow (although they are way faster than the naive solution). It takes about 5 hours to import my data that way (with 150k rows and 15 expected columns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way which should work even given your edited data. Extract the column names and values from your input vector using `regmatches`, then run through each list element matching the values to the appropriate column names.

```
#  Get column names
tag <- regmatches( input , gregexpr( "[a-z]+" , input ) )

#  Get numbers including floating point, replace missing values with NA
val <- regmatches( input , gregexpr( "\\d+\\.?\\d?|(?<=[a-z]);" , input , perl = TRUE ) )
val <- lapply( val , gsub , pattern = ";" , replacement = NA )

#  Column names
nms <- unique( unlist(tag) )

#  Intermeidate matrices
ll <- mapply( cbind , val , tag )

#  Match to appropriate columns and coerce to data.frame
out <- data.frame( do.call( rbind , lapply( ll , function(x) x[ match( nms , x[,2] ) ]  ) ) )
names(out) <- nms
#    an   bn   cn   dn
#1    1    3   45 <NA>
#2 <NA>  3.5   76 <NA>
#3    2 <NA> <NA>    5
```

Comment: Thanks for a 'base' solution! I'll try it out and compare then timings.

Comment: I just tried it and it seems very much faster! I still have to adjust some small things about the regmatches, but still this finishes in minutes instead hours.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am very glad this was useful for you! Great stuff. cheers :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is a kind of bad techniq but sometimes `ept`( `eval parse text`) is useful.

```
> library(plyr)
> rbind.fill(lapply(input, function(x) {l <- new.env(); eval(parse(text = x), envir=l); as.data.frame(as.list(l))}))
  an cn  bn dn
1  1 45 3.0 NA
2 NA 76 3.5 NA
3  2 NA  NA  5
```

**Update**

```
> z <- lapply(strsplit(input, ";"), 
+             function(x) {
+               e <- Filter(function(y) length(y)==2, strsplit(x, "="))
+               r <- data.frame(lapply(e, `[`, 2))
+               names(r) <- lapply(e, `[`, 1)
+               r
+             })
> rbind.fill(z)
    an   bn   cn   dn
1    1    3   45 <NA>
2 <NA>  3.5   76 <NA>
3    2 <NA> <NA>    5
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks way more concise than my solution. Unfortunately I cannot compare the timings between the solutions, because my input looks in fact slightly different than I thought, hence this solution doesn't work on it (See the EDIT2). But still, as this solution solved the initial problem I'll accept it.

Comment: Great, thanks! Compared to my above given naive solution this is about 9 times faster!

Answer (score 2):

Not really efficient, and use an external package.

1. convert each line to a data.frame
2. rbinds them using `rbind.fill` from `plyr`

Here my code:

```
ll <- lapply(input,function(x){
        xx <- unlist(strsplit(x,";"))
        nn <- sub('([a-z]+)[=].*','\\1',xx)
        vv <- sub('([a-z]+)[=]([0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?)','\\2',xx)
        m <- t(data.frame(vv))
        colnames(m) <- nn
        as.data.frame(m)
})

library(plyr)
rbind.fill(ll)

rbind.fill(ll)
    an   bn   cn   dn
1    1    3   45 <NA>
2 <NA>  3.5   76 <NA>
3    2 <NA> <NA>    5
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, unfortunately I cannot accept all answers but at least +1.

Answer (score 1):

One more variation on the `rbind.fill` theme:

```
library(plyr)

mini.df <- function(x) {
  y <- do.call(cbind,strsplit(x,"="))
  z <- as.numeric(y[2,])
  names(z) <- y[1,]
  return(as.data.frame(t(z)))
}
res <- rbind.fill(lapply(strsplit(input,";"),mini.df))
```

This is actually very similar to the other two solutions.  I just created the dataframes slightly differently.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, unfortunately I cannot accept all answers but at least +1.