# Combine two Matrix with different row count

Tags: r

I would like to combine two matrices with different row count:

```
k<-c(11,21,31,4,5,6,7,8,9)
k<-as.matrix(k)
m<-c(10,20,30,4,5,6)
m<-as.matrix(m)
```

I am using this command but doesnt work correctly for me:

```
j<-merge(m,k,all=TRUE)
```

what should I do to do this job

**EDIT**

I would like to have something like this:

```
   [,1]  [,2]
[1,] 11    10
[2,] 21    20 
[3,] 31    30
[4,] 4     4
[5,] 5     5
[6,] 6     6
[7,] 7     NA
[8,] 8     NA
[9,] 9     NA
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to how exactly you would like to combine the matrices. Are you simply looking for `rbind()`, assuming that the numbers of *columns* are identical?

Comment: I would like to `cbind` but I get an error: number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)

Comment: What result do you expect from `cbind()`, taking into account that, indeed, the number of rows is unequal? `cbind(1:9,1:6)` may be what you are looking for, which recycles the shorter vector and gives a warning. I suggest thinking about *why* you would want to `cbind` vectors of unequal length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you would like to merge m and k colwise...

```
library(zoo)

my_k <- zoo(k)
my_m <- zoo(m)

j <- as.matrix(merge(my_m, my_k))
```

Comment: thank you :) how can I do the same thing for `rbind` with different column count?

Comment: @Kaja Take a look at library(plyr) and the function rbind.fill.matrix(). It might be usefull.

Comment: It needs RCpp, and Rcpp needs   R (≥ 3.0.0) and I cant upgrade my R.Is there another way to do this job?

Comment: there is another way [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003717/is-there-any-efficient-way-than-rbind-filllist) and anather [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308551/do-callrbind-list-for-uneven-number-of-column?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If there are only two vectors, probably simplest to make them both the same length

```
mlen <- max(length(m), length(k))
length(m) <- length(k) <- mlen
cbind(m,k)
```

will give the required result.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
k <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:9, 11,21,31,4,5,6,7,8,9), 9,2))
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1:6, 10,20,30,4,5,6), 6, 2))
j <- as.matrix(merge(k,m, by = "V1", all.x = T)[, -1])
```

Comment: thanks, but if I use it I get: `Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid column(s)`

Comment: Ok, I didn't have that error, but I modified the answer so you won't have it too. Try now