# How to stack input from two csv files?

Tags: r, csv, comparison

I am trying to use the `stack` command on data loaded from two text csv files I want to compare. I want to use `crossprod(table(stack(data)))` to see how many strings the different columns have in common (In the example it would be "dog" and "cat").
In this example the csv files contain columns with different numbers of strings.

```
> one<-read.delim("one.csv",sep="\t",header=F)
> two<-read.delim("two.csv",sep="\t",header=F)

> one
       V1
1     dog
2 hamster
3   mouse
4     cat

> two
      V1
1    dog
2    cat
3 rabbit

> data<-list(one,two)
> stack(data)
Error in stack.default(data) : at least one vector element is required
```

If I manually create lists with `one<-c("dog",...)` it works. What am I doing wrong, and how can I do this right?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with your files? How are you going to compare them?

Comment: why dont you try `df <- data.frame(one, two); stack(df)`

Comment: @PauloCardoso data.frame does not work because the columns have different lenghts. I need to use stack because I want to compare how many strings the columns of the different files have in common. I want to use `crossprod(table(stack(data)))` to compare.

Comment: Do you have only two data.frames and both with only one column? In that case `x <- as.character(one[,1]);
y <- as.character(two[,1]);
sum(x %in% y)` should work

Comment: @Andromeda I have tab delimited csv files containing several columns of which I need to compare the one providing different nominal values. So the data frames I get have each only one column with different nominal values.

Comment: you could try to `plyr::rbind.fill(...)` or see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17309310/640783)

Comment: @Andromeda This approach seems to work on the example. I will try it with my original data. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems here that you need to address in order to get `stack` to work as you intend it to.

1. `stack` will not do anything to `factor` variables.
2. `stack` works with named lists.
3. `stack` does not work with nested lists, and a `data.frame` is a special type of list.

Let's look at addressing each of these:

*Make sure that your `read.table` includes `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`*. Here, I'm creating two `data.frame`s with that argument included.

```
one <- data.frame(V1 = c("dog", "hamster", "mouse", "cat"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
two <- data.frame(V1 = c("dog", "cat", "rabbit"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

*Make sure that your `list` is a named `list`.*

```
data <- list(one = one, two = two)
```

Two requirements down... test. Error remains....

```
stack(data)
# Error in stack.default(data) : at least one vector element is required
```

*"Flatten" your `list`, but not fully--use `recursive = FALSE`.* Test with `stack`:

```
stack(unlist(data, recursive=FALSE))
#    values    ind
# 1     dog one.V1
# 2 hamster one.V1
# 3   mouse one.V1
# 4     cat one.V1
# 5     dog two.V1
# 6     cat two.V1
# 7  rabbit two.V1
```

From there, you can do your `t/crossprod`:

```
tcrossprod(table(stack(unlist(data, recursive=FALSE))))
#          values
# values    cat dog hamster mouse rabbit
#   cat       2   2       1     1      1
#   dog       2   2       1     1      1
#   hamster   1   1       1     1      0
#   mouse     1   1       1     1      0
#   rabbit    1   1       0     0      1
```